# Display excluded images on product view also

Tags: magento-1.9

We changed templates, and also got a new image zoom. With our former image zoom we had to exclude image 1 to prevent it from displaying twice on product view page. With the new image zoom our first image is excluded (how it should be when excluded checkbox is active).

We have serveral thousands of products, so I am looking for a solution to change the PHP code to display all excluded images on frontend also. This way I don't need to change the settings for each product.

This is the media.phtml file that came with my template. I would like to know what to edit to make excluded images visible.

```
    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();
?>
<?php
    $aspect_ratio = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/aspect_ratio", $code);
    $ratio_width = 600;
    $ratio_height = 600;
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_width", $code))
        $ratio_width = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_width", $code);
    if(!$aspect_ratio){
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_height", $code))
            $ratio_height = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/ratio_height", $code);
    }
    $ratio = $ratio_height / $ratio_width;
    $rnd_str = rtrim(base64_encode(md5(microtime())),"=");
?>
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<ul id="etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>">
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <li>
        <?php
            if(!$aspect_ratio)
                $image_src=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($ratio_width, $ratio_height);
            else
                $image_src=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($ratio_width);
        ?>
        <a rel="gallery" class="fancy-images fancy-images_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>" href="<?php echo $image_src; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
        <img class="etalage_source_image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(100, 100*$ratio)?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>"/>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php else: ?>
<ul id="etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>">
    <li>
        <?php
            if(!$aspect_ratio)
                $image_src=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($ratio_width, $ratio_height);
            else
                $image_src=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($ratio_width);
        ?>
        <a class="fancy-images fancy-images_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>" href="<?php echo $image_src; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"/>
        <img class="etalage_source_image" src="<?php echo (!$aspect_ratio)?$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(100, $ratio_height/$ratio_width*100):$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(100);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()) ?>" />
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="etalage-control">
<?php if (!Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/general/rtl",$code)) : ?>
    <a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" class="etalage-prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" class="etalage-next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" class="etalage-prev"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript&colon;void(0)" class="etalage-next"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php
    $zoom_disabled = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/disable_product_zoom", $code);
    $zoom_type = Mage::getStoreConfig("porto_settings/product_view/zoom_type", $code);
?>
<div class="product-view-zoom-area">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        reloadEtalage();
        <?php if(!$zoom_disabled): ?>
        jQuery(".product-img-box .etalage li.etalage_thumb").zoom({
        <?php if($zoom_type == 1): ?>
            target: jQuery(".product-view-zoom-area"),
        <?php endif; ?>
            touch:false
        });
        <?php endif; ?>
        setTimeout(function(){reloadEtalage();}, 500);
        jQuery(window).resize(function(e){
            reloadEtalage();
            var width = jQuery(this).width();
        });
        jQuery('.etalage-prev').on('click', function(){ etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>_previous(); });
        jQuery('.etalage-next').on('click', function(){ etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>_next(); });
        jQuery("a.fancy-images_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>").fancybox();
        function reloadEtalage(){
            var width = jQuery('.product-view .product-img-box').width()-8;
            var src_img_width = <?php echo $ratio_width; ?>;
            var src_img_height = "auto";
            var ratio_width = <?php echo $ratio_width; ?>;
            var ratio_height = <?php echo $ratio_height; ?>;

            var height = "auto";
            jQuery('#etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>').etalage({
                thumb_image_width: width,
                thumb_image_height: height,
                source_image_width: src_img_width,
                source_image_height: src_img_height,
                zoom_area_width: width,
                zoom_area_height: height,
                zoom_enable: false,
                small_thumbs:4,
                smallthumb_hide_single: false,
                smallthumbs_position: 'bottom',
                small_thumbs_width_offset: 0,
                show_icon: false,
                autoplay: false
            });

            var first_img = jQuery("#etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?> img.etalage_thumb_image").first();
            var tmp_img = jQuery('<img src="" alt=""/>');
            tmp_img.attr("src",first_img.attr("src"));
            tmp_img.unbind("load");
            tmp_img.bind("load",function(){
                jQuery("#etalage_<?php echo $rnd_str; ?>").height(Math.round(width*this.naturalHeight/this.naturalWidth+8)+"px");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of showing excluded images I would change their status `exclude` to `not-exclude` programmatically or via database.

If you have access to your database, check `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table and see **disabled** column and you will see few having value as `1`, which means they are excluded images.

You can just use `sql` query to change their status to `not-excluded`-

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET disabled = 0
```

This will set all your images (excluded) to non-excluded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked out great Adarsh. My problem is solved instantly. You saved me a lot of work changing this manual, so thank you very much!

Comment: Glad, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code to display only excluded images, in file media.phtml

```
    if($_image->getDisabledDefault()==1){ 
 //display image code here
   }
```